# RuntimeError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 2.86 GiB (GPU 0; 10.92 GiB total capacity;...9.06 GiB reserved in total by PyTorch)

Tags: pytorch, gpu, nvidia

What does it mean by `9.06 GiB reserved in total by PyTorch`.

If i use a GPU of smaller size `7.80 GiB total capacity` for the same script, it says `6.20 GiB reserved in total by PyTorch`
How does reservation in Pytorch work and why does the reserved memory change depending on the GPU size?

To solve the error message, `RuntimeError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 2.86 GiB (GPU 0; 10.92 GiB total capacity; 9.02 GiB already allocated; 1.29 GiB free; 9.06 GiB reserved in total by PyTorch)` I have tried reducing the batch size from 10 to 5 to 3. 
I have tried deleting unused tensors with `del x_train1`. I have also tried using `torch.cuda.empty_cache()`. I have also used `with torch.no_grad()` when applying the pretrained model at `x_train1 = bert_model(train_indices)[2]` and also when training and validating the new model. But none of them work.

This is the trace:

```
cuda:0
    x_train1 = bert_model(train_indices)[2]  # Models outputs are tuples
  File "/home/kosimadukwe/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 532, in __call__
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/home/kosimadukwe/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transformers/modeling_bert.py", line 783, in forward
    input_ids=input_ids, position_ids=position_ids, token_type_ids=token_type_ids, inputs_embeds=inputs_embeds
  File "/home/kosimadukwe/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 532, in __call__
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/home/kosimadukwe/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transformers/modeling_bert.py", line 177, in forward
    embeddings = inputs_embeds + position_embeddings + token_type_embeddings
RuntimeError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 2.86 GiB (GPU 0; 10.92 GiB total capacity; 9.02 GiB already allocated; 1.29 GiB free; 9.06 GiB reserved in total by PyTorch)
```

and nvidia-smi out put

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 440.36       Driver Version: 440.36       CUDA Version: 10.2     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 108...  Off  | 00000000:3B:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 54%   79C    P2   233W / 250W |   8613MiB / 11178MiB |    100%   E. Process |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  GeForce GTX 108...  Off  | 00000000:AF:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 58%   79C    P2   247W / 250W |   4545MiB / 11178MiB |      0%   E. Process |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   2  GeForce GTX 108...  Off  | 00000000:D8:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 23%   29C    P0    56W / 250W |      0MiB / 11178MiB |      2%   E. Process |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   1025219      C   /usr/pkg/bin/python3.8                      8601MiB |
|    1   1024440      C   /usr/pkg/bin/python3.8                      4535MiB |
```

with

```
os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = '2'
```